# Null OR generic as parameter method

Tags: c#, generics

In Java you can do this:

```
protected void makeRequest<T extends BaseJsonClass, T2 extends BaseJsonClass> (Response<T> response, T2 dataToSend, String url) {}
```

Some request:

```
makeRequest(response, null, serverUrl);
makeRequest(response, jsonData, serverUrl);
```

In C# how?

I'm writing a method that should be able to accept data as null or as a specific type of object.

```
/**
 * Make a request to the server.
 * dataToSend can be null.
 * */
protected void makeRequest<T, T2>(Response<T> response, T2 dataToSend, string url) where T : JsonObjectBase where T2 : JsonObjectBase
{ }
```

Currently I'm getting the problem:

```
The type arguments for method `BaseModelController.makeRequest<T,T2>(Response<T>, T2, string)'
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

How would I allow a generic that can possibly be null as well?

** EDIT 1 **
I invoke this method like so:
`makeRequest(response, null, serverUrl);`
or
`makeRequest(response, someJsonData, serverUrl);`

** EDIT 2 **

`JsonObjectBase` is just an object that is extended by other Json classes so I can parse/serialize them auto-magically knowing that it will always be a Json object. I use it for type checking so other coders don't make the mistake of entering an unknown object.
Passing null is really much better than defining the same value which is 'suppose' to not do anything; because that gets messy very fast.

Example of the power

```
ModelControllerAccount.getInstance().createUser(
            username.text, password.text, // Params
            new Response<JsonUserAccountFeedback>(
                success: (jsonObjectStandardResponse) => Debug.Log("Success when creating account. Data: " + jsonObjectStandardResponse.getAccessToken()),
                failed: (failedReason) => Debug.Log("Failed to make request. Reason: " + failedReason.getReasonDescription())
            )
        );
```

Comment: How do you invoke this method?

Comment: Try casting null to whatever type you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're most likely only need access to the methods of JsonObjectBase you could do something like this:

```
    protected void MakeRequest<T>(Response<T> response, JsonObjectBase dataToSend, string url) where T : JsonObjectBase
    {    
    }
```

and call the method like this: `MakeRequest(response, null, serverUrl);`

Or you could even take advantage of optional arguments:

```
    protected void MakeRequest<T>(Response<T> response, string url, JsonObjectBase dataToSend = null) where T : JsonObjectBase
    {
    }
```

and call the method like this: `MakeRequest(response, serverUrl);`

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the API somewhat, one easy way to fix this would be to add an overload that omits the second parameter. This is easier for the caller too in cases where you're not sending any data.

Like this:

```
protected void makeRequest<T>(Response<T> response, string url) where T : JsonObjectBase 
{ 
    makeRequest (response, default(JsonObjectBase), url); 
}
```

Comment: Then I'd have to repeat the code? When you say overload do you mean just another method?

Comment: You can outsource the code into a second method which is called by both methods so you don't have to repeat the code

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - Yes. I edited my answer to show one possible implementation of the overload-- it can simply call the other method casting the null to JsonObjectBase.  You can also do the same thing in your caller's code, but IMHO having an overload seems easier for the caller.

Comment: I'm getting ```Cannot implicitly convert type T2 to string```

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - I edited the overload definition to match your types. Take a look at the latest code.

Comment: And now; how do I access the Json object to send data?

Comment: If JsonObjectBase is not a reference type or a nullable type, then you won't be able to cast null into JsonObjectBase. So instead you'd need to pick some non-null value in the overload's implementation that represents "no data to send".  Or you can use `default(JsonObjectBase)` which returns null for reference types but default values for value types. To answer your second question: if you're not sending any data, then I'm not sure why you want to access the JSON object-- all you need to know is that it's empty, right?

Comment: I want the option to send data or not. That was the idea behind null. I'd check if it was null, if not send data. :-)

Comment: Could you post (in your original question) the definition of JsonObjectBase?  it's odd that you can't cast a null to that type.

Comment: ```JsonObjectBase``` is just an object that is extended by other Json classes so I can parse/serialize them auto-magically. I use it for type checking so other coders don't make the mistake of entering an unknown object. 

Passing null is really much better than defining the same value which is 'suppose' to not do anything; because that gets messy very fast.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because a value of `null` doesn't tell the compiler the type of that parameter. After all, the implementation of `makeRequest` could check the type of `T2` and do wildly different things depending on what it sees. If you had passed, say, a variable with the type of `List<int>`, it would know that `T2` is `List<int>`, but `null` could be the value of any reference type. If the compiler can't figure out the type (or if it ever decides the wrong one), you'll need to tell it:

```
Response<string> myResponse;
makeRequest<Response<string>, object>(myResponse, null, "http://example.com");
```

I've just specified the types used to call the generic method. In this case, the type of the `null` parameter is `object`.

Comment: Then I lose the power of abstraction and generics though my model controller.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns If the calling method takes a generic type parameter `T`, you can pass `default(T)` instead of `null` and not have to use the specific generic call thing.